# Open an MVC application on a button click from CRM

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, actionresult

I am making an MVC4 application which is displaying data from CRM.

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)  
{  
    MyApplication.Data.ResourceData resourceData = new MyApplication.Data.ResourceData();  
    var resource1 = resourceData.showResource(id);

    return View(resource1);
    //return View();
}
```

I have created a button in CRM and when I click the button I get Id
get url **www.MyApplication.com?123456**  where 123456 is Id of the Data in CRM.

Now how to parse data to open my application.

I mean how to tell my **MVC application** to  take the string after **?** and as Id which needs to be pased in Index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a key to the url.  change it to www.MyApplication.com?id=123456.  then in your controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string id){...}
```

should catch the id.  If that doesn't pull the id then Request.QueryString["id"] should get it also.  Hopefully this helps.